# Web Scraping with python using Selenium and Chromedriver

Tags: web-scraping

I am using Selenium to scrape the data from web. However, when I try to run the Chromedriver it seems to run fine but no data has been extracted when I look into the csv file I export in the last. Additionally,when I time sleep the algorithm for 5 seconds and do right click + inspect it seems to work fine? Anybody knows what could be the issue and how can I fully automate the process without requiring the user to right click + inspect?

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: Is there a way to automate the right click +inpect operation using selenium in python?